# LD_PRELOAD not working on Heroku + jemalloc + quotaguard

Tags: heroku, ld-preload, jemalloc, quotaguard

**TL;DR:** update your `bin/qgtunnel`.

---

I've recently noticed an increase in my web dyno's memory usage. After digging a bit, I could see that the `LD_PRELOAD` variable that should be set with [heroku-buildpack-jemalloc](https://github.com/gaffneyc/heroku-buildpack-jemalloc) was not set correctly. I used a tiny script (`bin/show_preload`) that helped me debug that and trace which program was overriding `LD_PRELOAD`.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "buildpack=foo preload='$LD_PRELOAD' at=start-app cmd='$@'"
$@
```

I introduced that in our `Procfile`:

```
web: bin/show_preload bin/qgtunnel bin/show_preload bin/start-nginx bin/show_preload bin/start-pgbouncer bin/show_preload bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

And when lauching on heroku I can see that `bin/qgtunnel` overrides our `LD_PRELOAD` configuration.

I created a tiny helper for the time being which makes sure I keep original value as well as what is added by `bin/qgtunnel`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

after_qgtunnel_script=$(mktemp)
echo <<-BASH > $after_qgtunnel_script
    # Retrieve previous LD_PRELOAD value
    export LD_PRELOAD="\$LD_PRELOAD $LD_PRELOAD"

    # Clean after usage
    rm $after_qgtunnel_script

    # Start following commands
    $@
BASH

chmod +x $after_qgtunnel_script

bin/qgtunnel $after_qgtunnel_script $@
```

If you ever need this script use it **in place of** `bin/qgtunnel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out to Quotaguard, they patched the `qgtunnel` binary and there is no error anymore:

```sh
curl https://quotaguard.s3.amazonaws.com/qgtunnel-2.4.1.tar.gz | tar xz
git add bin/qgtunnel vendor/nss_wrapper/libnss_wrapper.so
git commit -m "Update qgtunnel to fix LD_PRELOAD"
```

<sub>**NOTE**: new versions may occur since that one, see [the related documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic#download-qgtunnel)</sub>